# Create .pem file for public key RSA encryption C# .net

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I want to create `.pem` file for the public key generated by this method

```
public static Tuple<string, string> CreateKeyPair()
{
    CspParameters cspParams = 
        new CspParameters { 
            ProviderType = 1 /* PROV_RSA_FULL */ 
        };

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = 
        new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParams);

    string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
    string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));

    return new Tuple<string, string>(privateKey, publicKey);
}
```

Because I was generating this key for mobile application and they can not read it, they requested `.pem` file instead of public key as string

Please advice,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, a so-called `.pem` file is not really a fixed specification or format. Several different kinds of distinct file formats are generally described as "PEM" files. When the SSLeay (now OpenSSL) project needed to produce a base64 encoded output file containing key information they borrowed formatting concepts from the old Privacy-Enhanced Mail RFCs [1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421)-1424 and they added the extension `.pem` to the end of these files. But such a file may contain public keys, private keys, certificate requests, certificates, certificate lists, and so on. Each is different. So if all you're told is to produce a `.pem` file you're going to have to guess what's really needed.

The easiest way to write such files is to use the [Bouncycastle C# library](http://bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html). The package `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl` contains a number of utilities including a `PemWriter` class that should help you.

Comment: Don't use `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl`, because it has no examples and very bad documentation for C#! I worked under the same problem, and this library really helps me: `https://github.com/jrnker/CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM`. It has good examples and you can solve your problem using only *one* *line* (instead of implement some interfaces from `BouncyCastle`)!

Comment: @V.Panchenko: Thanks for your comment. Please consider writing an answer to this question with the one-liner as an example.

Comment: CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM is GPL3 licensed, so you can't use it unless your project is GPL too. BouncyCastle on the other hand is MIT

Answer (score 12):

Recently I need to save `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` generated in my C# application to file, and works with it later. I use for this purpose such library as [CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM](https://github.com/jrnker/CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM).

It is very simple and quick solution, so I will recommend this library to other guys.

I use following code to get `PublicKey` as `string` (and save it to `pem` file in format `Base64`):

```
string publicKeyStr = Crypto.ExportPublicKeyToX509PEM(_cryptoServiceProvider);
```

it returns something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCxnBvS8cdsnAev2sRDRYWxznm1
QxZzaypfNXLvK7CDGk8TR7K+Pzsa+tpJfoyN/Z4B6xdlpsERo2Cu6AzolvrDLx5w
ZoI0kgdfaBMbUkdOB1m97zFYjKWoPeTskFzWZ3GHcQ3EXT0NJXXFXAskY45vEpbc
5qFgEhcPy3BMqHRibwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And I use following code to get `PrivateKey` as `string`:

```
string privateKeyStr = Crypto.ExportPrivateKeyToRSAPEM(_cryptoServiceProvider);
```

it returns something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICWwIBAAKBgQCxnBvS8cdsnAev2sRDRYWxznm1QxZzaypfNXLvK7CDGk8TR7K+
Pzsa+tpJfoyN/Z4B6xdlpsERo2Cu6AzolvrDLx5wZoI0kgdfaBMbUkdOB1m97zFY
jKWoPeTskFzWZ3GHcQ3EXT0NJXXFXAskY45vEpbc5qFgEhcPy3BMqHRibwIDAQAB
AoGAAdwpqm7fxh0S3jOYpJULeQ45gL11dGX7Pp4CWHYzq1vQ14SDtFxYfnLWwGLz
499zvSoSHP1pvjPgz6lxy9Rw8dUxCgvh8VQydMQzaug2XD1tkmtcSWInwFKBAfQ7
rceleyD0aK8JHJiuzM1p+yIJ/ImGK0Zk2U/svqrdJrNR4EkCQQDo3d5iWcjd3OLD
38k1GALEuN17KNpJqLvJcIEJl0pcHtOiNnyy2MR/XUghDpuxwhrhudB/TvX4tuI0
MUeVo5fjAkEAw0D6m9jkwE5uuEYN/l/84rbQ79p2I7r5Sk6zbMyBOvgl6CDlJyxY
434DDm6XW7c55ALrnlratEW5HPiPxuHZBQJANnE4vtGy7nvn4Fd/mRQmAYwe695f
On1iefP9lxpx3huu6uvGN6IKPqS2alQZ/nMdCc0Be+IgC6fmNsGWtNtsdQJAJvB4
ikgxJqD9t8ZQ2CAwgM5Q0OTSlsGdIdKcOeB3DVmbxbV5vdw8RfJFjcVEbkgWRYDH
mKcp4rXc+wgfNFyqOQJATZ1I5ER8AZAn5JMMH9zK+6oFvhLUgKyWO18W+dbcFrBd
AzlTB+HHYEIyTmaDtXWAwgBvJNIHk4BbM1meCH4QnA==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then you can use

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicX509key = Crypto.DecodeX509PublicKey(publicKeyStr);
RSACryptoServiceProvider privateRSAkey = Crypto.DecodeRsaPrivateKey(privateKeyStr);
```

to restore saved keys back to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

So, if someone need to resolve similar issue, you can just download [this](https://github.com/jrnker/CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM) library, go to `Solution Explorer -> (Right click on your project) -> Add -> Reference -> Overview` in your `Visual Studio` to add this library in your project, and add `using CSharp_easy_RSA_PEM;` where you need it :)

Comment: Looks like a nice solution.

Comment: I'd give it an upvote if it had a liberal license, but alas, it is GPL.