# How to convert .crt file to .pem file in c#

Tags: c#, openssl, pem, crt, der

I have the crt file and I need to convert it to pem by code in C#, how can I do that?

command in openssl:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in file.crt -out file.pem
```

Comment: If you already know the command to run, what's stopping you from starting that process in C#?

Comment: @gunr2171 I think the point is that OP wants pure C# code, without resorting to external Unix applications with horrible command lines. AFAIK there is no native support for PEM in `X509Certificate2` so might be difficult. There must be a dupe somewhere

Comment: exactly what @Charlieface said, I didn't want to have to resort to external Unix applications and do it directly through my project

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296996/2557128 or possibly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941142/2557128

Comment: What .Net are you using?

Comment: version 4.6.1 @NetMage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On modern versions of .NET you can use the [PemEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pemencoding?view=net-6.0) class:

.NET 7:

```
string pem = PemEncoding.WriteString("CERTIFICATE", der);
```

.NET 5:

```
string pem = new string(PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE", der));
```

But, in "stone-aged" .NET Framework you have to write the fairly easy transform yourself (`$"-----BEGIN {label}-----\n{Convert.ToBase64String(der, Base64FormattingOptions.IncludeNewLines)}\n-----END {label}-----\n"` being the short form).

Borrowed/tweaked from the Remarks section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest.createsigningrequest?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-certificaterequest-createsigningrequest:

```
private static string PemEncode(string label, byte[] der)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append("-----BEGIN ");
    builder.Append(label);
    builder.AppendLine("-----");

    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pkcs10);

    int offset = 0;
    const int LineLength = 64;

    while (offset < base64.Length)
    {
        int lineEnd = Math.Min(offset + LineLength, base64.Length);
        builder.AppendLine(base64.Substring(offset, lineEnd - offset));
        offset = lineEnd;
     }

     builder.Append("-----END ");
     builder.Append(label);
     builder.AppendLine("-----");
     return builder.ToString();
}
```